# Show that there are exactly $\aleph_0$-many countable $L$-structure if $L$ consists of one unary relation symbol.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, model-theory

$\textbf{First question:}$
Let $L=\{R\}$ be a language consisting of one unary relation symbol. Show that there are exactly $\aleph_0$-many countable $L$-structures up to isomorphism.

My (attempted) solution is as follows: Let $\mathcal{M}=(M,R^{\mathcal{M}})$ be an $L$-structure. Since $R$ is a unary relation symbol, the basic relation $R^{\mathcal{M}}$ is also unary. But a unary relation is just a subset of $M$. Any countable $L$-structure is isomorphic to $\omega$ or some $n \in \omega$. So the set of all countable $L$-structures up to isomorphism is 
$$\{(n,E):n \in \omega,E \subseteq n\} \cup \{(\omega,F):F \subseteq \omega\}$$

We first look at the set one the left hand side. It is of cardinality $\aleph_0$. If I can show the set on the right hand side is also of cardinality $\aleph_0$ then we are done. But how?

$|\mathcal{P}(\omega)|=\aleph_1$ hence the cardinality of the set on the right is $\aleph_1$. $\textbf{What did I do wrong?}$

$\textbf{Second question:}$ Let $L=\{R\}$ be a language consisting of one unary relation symbol. How many $L$-structure of size $\aleph_1$ are there?

I was trying to use the similar argument as in my first question, but in the first question, we consider countable structures and we know every countable set is isomorphic to $\omega$ or some $n \in \omega$. But if we consider structures of cardinality $\aleph_1$, I don't know the particular set they are isomorphic to, so I can't use the argument as before. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, $|\mathcal{P}(\omega)| = \aleph_1$ is the statement of the continuum hypothesis, which is not provable in ZFC. The correct statement is $|\mathcal{P}(\omega)| = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

As to what you're doing wrong, note that if $E$ is the set of even numbers, and $O$ is the set of odd numbers, then $(\omega,E)\cong (\omega,O)$, even though these structures are not equal. So when you look at $\{(\omega,F)\mid F\subseteq \omega\}$, you're vastly overcounting.

Instead, prove that up to isomorphism, a countable structure in the language with a single unary relation symbol $R$ is totally determined by the cardinality of the set of elements $R$ and the cardinality of the set of elements not in $R$. These two cardinalities can be $0$, $1$, $2$,$\dots$ or $\aleph_0$.

The same sort of reasoning works for structures of size $\aleph_1$.

Aside: For structures of size $\aleph_1$, you write "I don't know the particular set they are isomorphic to..." Any set of size $\aleph_1$ is isomorphic to the **set** $\aleph_1$, namely the first uncountable ordinal.

Comment: Now I see. So the set on the right hand side should actually be $\{(\omega,F):F=\omega \vee F=n\}$ which has cardinality $\aleph_0$, right?

Comment: And according to this reasoning, for the second question, the set of all uncountable $L$-structure is $\{(\aleph_1,F): |F|=\aleph_1,\aleph_0,n\}$ which is again countable?

Comment: I guess you're trying to write down an explicit set of representatives for the countably infinite structures up to isomorphism? One such set is $\{(\omega,F)\mid F = n,n\in \omega\}\cup \{(\omega,F)\mid F = \omega\setminus n,n\in \omega\} \cup \{(\omega,F)\mid F = \{2n\mid n\in \omega\}\}$.

Comment: (That is, the set you wrote down is missing the cases when $F$ is infinite but not all of $\omega$). The set of structures of size $\aleph_1$ (this is not the same as the set of *all* uncountable structures!) is indeed countable. But again, you need to account not just for the size of $F$, but also for the size of $\aleph_1\setminus F$ when $|F| = \aleph_1$.

Comment: Yes. As you have pointed out, two countably infinite subsets of $\omega$ are isomorphic to each other. So to count the set $\{(\omega,F)\}$ we are actually counting the number of finite subsets of $\omega$ (which is $\aleph_0$) plus the number of countably infinite subset of $\omega$ up to isomorphism (which is one). So the set $\{(\omega,F)\}$ has cardinality $\aleph_0$.

Comment: My point is that it's not true that any two countably infinite subsets of $\omega$ are isomorphic to each other. $(\omega,\omega)$ is not isomorphic to $(\omega,E)$, where $E$ is the set of even numbers.

Comment: Seems like I need to review some set theory. I will re-think about it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: So for the first question, the reason for there are exactly $\aleph_0$-many countable $L$-structures, is it because the cardinality of the  set you gave in the third comment is $\aleph_0$? Thanks!

Comment: @cciirrcclllee yes, that's right.